# ¿Cómo hacer un Update masivo en MySql con Where?

Tags: php

Estoy leyendo un archivo excel desde PHP, voy recogiendo los campos que me interesan y guardando en una variable los valores para despues construir el update.

```
foreach ($rowData as $key => $value) {
  blah blah...
  $sql2 .="(pcompra='".$pcompra."', margen='".$margen."')  WHERE iduser=45 AND 
  referencia='".$referencia."', ";
}
```

Hasta aqui bien, el problema es construir la consulta, porque lo anterior se que está mal y no se como construirlo para que el bulk update funcione correctamente.

Así he como he insertado los 6000 registros en una sola consulta, pero el UPDATE no se como hacerlo.

Mi tabla tiene una serie de campos, pero entre ellos tengo:

- ID (unico) <- pero no lo conozco en el update.
- iduser
- referencia <- es unica dependiendo del iduser
- pcompra2 <- quiero actualizarlo
- margen <- quiero actualizarlo

Ahora bien, tengo 6000 productos que actualizar.
¿Como podria actualizar los campos 'pcompra2' y 'margen' en los 6000 productos según iduser y referencia **en una sola sentencia**?

Intento algo como esto:

```
UPDATE stocks 
SET 
      (pcompra='5', margen='0.2')  WHERE iduser=45 AND referencia='00257', 
      (pcompra='6', margen='0.1')  WHERE iduser=45 AND referencia='00258', 
      (pcompra='2', margen='0.2')  WHERE iduser=45 AND referencia='00259', 
      .... hasta 6000.
```

Comment: No se entiende nada, ¿puedes explicarlo un poco mejor? Gracias.

Comment: Ya lo he reescrito con otras palabras...

Comment: Es que no veo de dónde sacar automatización (update masivo) en el contexto que explicas ¿?  Ni veo de dónde se sacan los valores que vas poniendo a `pcompra` y a `margen`.  Sigo sin entender...

Comment: Los saco con PHP leyendo un documento excel y desde el mismo archivo conecto con mysql e inserto la consulta.

Comment: ¿O sea que construyes una sentencia `UPDATE` leyendo ese documento y lo que quieres es saber cómo escribirla para que funcione?

Comment: Si he entendido bien lo que necesitas es un generador de script, ya que lo que quieres es que a partir de campos variables en el where se actualicen los 6000 campos. ¿Es correcto? @Ruiz86

Comment: @solamente si, he actualizado el post aclarando mas mi procedimiento.

Comment: @A.Cedano he actualizado el post aclarando mas mi procedimiento.

Comment: Debiste decir desde un principio que estabas usando PHP. Lo mejor en este caso sería usar transacciones y consultas preparadas para lanzar el update en un contexto controlado y blindado contra inyección SQL. ¿Usas mysqli  o PDO?

Comment: @A.Cedano mysqli y son consultas muy puntuales, el archivo php lo bloqueo despues de la consulta, por lo que no es necesaria seguridad en este caso.

Comment: La seguridad nunca está de más. Además las consultas preparadas son más que eso, cuando preparas una consulta significa que el plan de ejecución se hace una sola vez y no 6,000 veces o 6 millones de veces, por lo que la diferencia es enorme. Además, en estos casos es bueno usar  transacciones. La cuestión es que si hay algún fallo con transacciones reviertes todo al estado original, en un update uno a uno, si hay fallo será difícil saber qué fila se actualizó y qué fila no se actualizó. Si te interesa se puede intentar de ese modo. Si no, lo otro sería crear updates 1 a 1 e irlos ejecutando.

Comment: Si quieres una actualización no controlada (no recomendado), puedes construir una sentencia independiente en cada paso del bucle: **`$sqlUpdate="";
foreach(....){ 
    $sqlUpdate .="UPDATE stocks SET pcompra='$pcompra', margen='$margen' WHERE iduser=45 AND referencia='$referencia';"; 
}`** OJO a la declaración de `$sqlUpdate` fuera del bucle y a la terminación con `;` de la sentencia SQL **dentro de las comillas**... Luego fuera del bucle la ejecutas con **[`multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php)**.

Comment: Cambie la etiqueta, ya que el problema es en php y mysql no tiene nada que ver aca. La respuesta en base de datos es, no se puede, hay que hacer un where por update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al margen de las soluciones de los compañeros me he inventado una "solución" para quien tenga acceso a mysql.

Aviso que **es muy poco elegante** pero bastante rápida.

En PHP he creado el siguiente bucle:

```
if($cont>=100 AND $cont<=1000){
  echo $sql2 ="<br/>UPDATE stocks SET pcompra2='".$pcompra2."', margen='".$margen."' WHERE iduser='".$iduser."' AND referencia='".$codigo."';";
}
```

Esto crea 900 (o las que quieras) consultas UPDATE y las muestra en la ventana del navegador.

Pues copio y pego en mysql y listo, en 5 segundos esas 900 de las 6000 actualizadas.

Luego ya es cosa de cambiar los números del bucle.

Comment: Tambien podes construir las 6000 en excel.. esto mas que una solucion es un workaround a un problema que no tenias.. :/

Comment: Te entiendo, pero he conseguido lo que quería en pocos segundos.